# Scraping special symbols in a string angularjs

Tags: angularjs, character, symbols

I have a string that contains a hyphen "-". How do I scrap off the hyphen if I want to just have the letters? For eg I have this String "-KTxEMxrAY". How do I remove the hyphen such that it becomes "KTxEMxAY" ?

I am using AngularJS.

Comment: I have posted two answer, let me know please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this like, the exact you want :

```js
    function ClickToEditCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.modelFilter = '-KTxEMxrAY';
    $scope.modelFilter = $scope.modelFilter.replace('-','');
    
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="ClickToEditCtrl">
   {{ modelFilter}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression like

```
var string = string.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise you can use filter for this :

```js
function ClickToEditCtrl($scope) {
$scope.modelFilter = '-KTxEMxrAY';
//$scope.modelFilter = $scope.modelFilter.replace('-','');
 $scope.modelFilterNormalized = function(){
     return $scope.modelFilter = $scope.modelFilter.replace('-','');
};
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="ClickToEditCtrl">
   {{ modelFilter | filter:modelFilterNormalized() }}
  </div>
</div>
```